# Binary tree. Order of leaf nodes (tree traversal)

Tags: tree

This is a rather simple question, I've noticed that when I representate a tree, no matter which way I do it (post-order, in-order, pre-order) the leafs always come up in the same order, left to right.

I'm just wondering why, is there a reason for this?

I'm just starting studying them and came up with this.

EDIT.:

I've got a tree like this:

```
        A
    B       C
  D       E   F
```

The leaf nodes are: D,E and F

The pre-order is: A,B,D,C,E,F

The in-order is: D,B,A,E,C,F

The post-order is: D,B,E,F,C,A

The leaf nodes always appear from left to right, no matter which order I choose. The question is why is it like this. What is the use given to these nodes for them to appear in this order.

I've been reading that these kind of trees are used as a representation for recursive procedures, so my guess is that right leaf nodes are cases which appear afterwards the left leaf nodes happened, and that's why they appear in any representation later on?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, regardless of where you put the node in the order, you are always visiting the left child before the right child. However, I'm not entirely sure that your observation will necessarily always be true, if your leaves are not all at the same distance from the root - I may be wrong, though...

Comment: Well, yeah, but my question is if there is a practical purpose for this fact.

Answer (score 2):

All These Traversals: Preorder, Inorder and Postorder Traversals are Depth-First Traversals. In All of them, Left Node is processed before Right Node (only the Root oscillates):

```
Preorder :  <ROOT>  LEFT   RIGHT
Inorder  :  LEFT   <ROOT>  RIGHT
Postorder:  LEFT    RIGHT <ROOT>
```

In each of these traversals, we are ultimately moving from left towards right.

Hence, Leaf-Nodes always come-up sequentially in the same order - in all three traversals.

There was a point in the above solution regarding leaves at different distance from the root. I verified it against the following example:

[image]

```
PreOrder - 8, 5, 9, 7, 1, 12, 2, 4, 11, 3
InOrder - 9, 5, 1, 7, 2, 12, 8, 4, 3, 11
PostOrder - 9, 1, 2, 12, 7, 5, 3, 11, 4, 8
```

The sequencing holds true even in this case

Purpose: It looks more like a consequence of the Left-Right pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in all those traversals you visit left subtree before the right subtree.